# devise, how to get the newly created user in custom registrations controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to add some additional logic to registrations with devise. I have two sign up forms, one which has additional fields for another object which is connected via a habtm relationship. I have extended the devise registrations controller and created the new object if it is present, but I am unsure of how to get the newly created user in this method.

In my custom registrations_controller.rb:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    unless params[:business].nil?
      @business = Business.new(params[:business])
    end
    super
    #@user.businesses << @business  #how can I implement something like this?
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

I did something very similar to this before. Check out this question [Make a fields_for block conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518109/make-a-fields-for-block-conditional)

There are two ways to do this. One is quick and dirty the other takes full advantage of rails.

**Method 1**

First in your model, make sure you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :businesses` then in your controller make sure you have something like

```
params[:user][:businesses] = [ params[:business] ]
```

**Method 2**

One of the things you may want to do instead, is use your models to your advantage. Using in your view a `fields_for` block allows you to specify relations that can be assumed from how your model is setup.

Still make sure that you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :businesses` in your model

In your controller you'll need to make some changes.

```
def new
  resource = build_resource({})
  resource.businesses.build  # Inserts a blank object for business
  respond_with resource
end
```

Now don't touch anything in create action, as in you can remove the bits of code you've added.

In the view, where you have the your business form along with your registration form. Add something like.

```
<% form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  # some user form stuff
  <%= f.fields_for :business do |i| %>
    <%= render "/users/registrations/business", :form => i %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

On save your controller should recognize that you're adding a business to user automatically.

You may need to play around with actual formatting and naming, but that makes submitting forms in Rails so much nicer to work with.  It also goes with the ideology to keep controllers nice and thin.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. It was not easily grokked from the source code.

Answer (score 1):

The newly-created `User` object is available as variable `resource`.

So, `resource.businesses << @business` would work.